# Is there a way to remotely edit iTunes playlists?

Tags: itunes, playlists

Essentially, my use case is that I want to edit the iTunes playlists on my desktop computer at home when I'm not in front of that computer.

A specific example:  I'm at my computer at work, and I want to add a song (that's already in my library) to an already-existing playlist in iTunes at home.

Comment: Itunes is scriptable [via COM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/05/08/128645.aspx).  So it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to remotely control your computer using [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com) or something similar.  Simply sign up for a free account, verify your email address, install the software on the target computer, then remotely control it from their website.

In your case, you'd install the LogMeIn software on your home computer; then you can control it remotely from work. This way you'd be able to do **anything** on your computer, not just modify iTunes playlists.

Comment: Looks great - I was actually going to mention something like this, but I assumed they would require me to install something on the remote computer.  The fact that this works in a remote browser is amazing.  Hopefully will get to try this tonight!

Comment: I can't believe how well that works.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Log me in is good paid way.

If anyone is looking for a free alternative, I would recommend TeamViewer as well.